# Magento Multiple Sites from pointer domain

Tags: multistore, multidomain

I have a Magento installation running having two websites by using sub domain for each 
The structure is Like follows

**Website 1** (Default)  
  store 1
  store view 1
  URL: aus.beautyhq.testpad.com.au

**Website 2**
  store 2
  store view 2
  URL: nz.beautyhq.testpad.com.au
This structure is working perfectly,

Now i need to create beta versions of them which have to have the base url from different url
I have created the new websites

1. Beta Website 1 -> URL : beautyhq-aus.domain.com.au
2. Beta Website 2 -> URL : beautyhq-nz.domain.com.au

And created the
directories(Including index.php and .htaccess with necessary changes) on Magento root according to the codes of new websites.

The new domain is from a different server and is pointing to the IP of the server hosting my Magento installation.

Now when I set the base URLs of these websites, it redirects to the default one, but if I change the base URL to `beautyhq.testpad.com.au/aus_beta/`, it works perfectly.

I have tried the solution for pointer domains by modifying the .htaccess and using `SetEnvIf` and `RewriteCond` by referring [this link](http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/)
But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Solution,
Not sure if its the best, but it works,
Added to addon domains same as the pointer domains and assigned them root directories of beta stores, and it worked.